# Dont know my login but know my password

Tags: login

I tried to upgrade to 16.4 and thought my computer had frozen half way through the process so I did a forced shutdown. Now when I try to get into ubuntu it is asking me to log in and my password. I know my password but I don't know my login. I am partitioned with windows and want to keep it that way. How can I login and finish the upgrade? Also will I lose any music,video and pictures?

Comment: It's your username

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading from an older version of Ubuntu, your login will stay the same.
If you freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04, called it an upgrade and rage-quit halfway through, the system asks you to choose your login on the same screen as you choose your password, way before you get anywhere close to halfway through, so YOU KNOW what your login is.